# Retry function call n times when function throw exception in y interval of time

Tags: java, java-8, scheduled-tasks, schedule, retry-logic

I wanted to retry my function call whenever it get failed in some duration of time.
What is the best way do this.
Is this will work fine.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            dndService.initateDNDRequest(transactionId, circle, category, "PREPAID");       
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);//wait for few minutes while next attempt
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                LOGGER.error("Error while retrying request for DND.");
            }
            LOGGER.error("Request retry for DND count"+i);
        }
    }
}, executor);
```

Comment: The trouble with catching `Exception` here is that there are **plenty** of exceptions which will never be resolved, even if you try a second or third time. It's pointless to try. You should only catch the things you're expecting might be resolved if you wait a little, for example exceptions related to the network.

Comment: Agree, thanks for the suggestion . Will it cause any issue in multi threaded enviroment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not put an executor’s worker thread to `sleep`.

One solution to schedule a new attempt, would be

```
    Executor executor; // … the actual executor
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Executor afterTenSeconds
        = r -> ses.schedule(() -> executor.execute(r), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Runnable primaryAction
        = () -> dndService.initateDNDRequest(transactionId, circle, category, "PREPAID");

    CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(primaryAction, executor);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cf = cf.handle((v,t) -> t == null? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(v):
                                CompletableFuture.runAsync(primaryAction, afterTenSeconds))
               .thenCompose(Function.identity());
    }
```

Then `handle` action will schedule a new attempt, to be executed after the timeout (ten seconds) in the failure case. The `thenCompose(Function.identity())` is necessary as there is no single method to combine `handle` and `compose` semantics.

Note that starting with Java 9, you can create the delayed executor as simple as

```
Executor afterTenSeconds = CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS,executor);
```

without the need to deal with `ScheduledExecutorService` yourself.

Comment: Thanks it waht i was looking for